# PHP/MySQL table update issue while checking condition in column

Tags: php, mysql, database

[image]

I have the above table: tblCompInfo, the product_id value is not 100% accurate and I need to fix it. I have total of 543847 total row with 25 different company and 12 different products.

now, The URL is 100% accurate and as you can see from the image I have highlighted with RED which means they are wrong and GREEN which is what it should be updated to.

TASK:
I need to update Product_id by parsing through URL and getting the INTEGER and checking it with product table, if its a product, assign the value else assign 0.

SOLUTION:
I got two solution in my head:

**1. EXPORT the entire DATA to EXCEL CVS, change it and UPLOAD it to DATABASE. which means my entire week will be working with EXCEL only.**

**2. Since I have laravel framework: I can make a function in PHP and get the DATA company wise and UPDATE the table in a foreach loop with condition.**

PROBLEM:
So, to make my life easy, I made the PHP function with a simple solution and it works BUT I get MEMORY ALLOCATION PROBLEM.

```
$companyID = ??;

$tblCompInfos = tblCompInfo::where('company_id', '=', $companyID)->get();

foreach($tblCompInfos as $tblCompInfo)
{
    $actual_link = $tblCompInfo->url;
    $pathlink = parse_url($actual_link, PHP_URL_PATH); 
    $product_id_from_url = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", "" , $pathlink); 
    $FindIfItsInProductTable = Product::find($product_id_from_url); 
    $real_product_id = $FindIfItsInProductTable == null ? 0 : $product_id_from_url;

    DB::table('tblCompInfo')->where('company_id', '=', $companyID)->where('url', '=', $tblCompInfo->url)->update(array(
        'product_id' => $real_product_id,
    ));

    echo $actual_link."-".$real_product_id."=".$tblCompInfo->product_id."<br>";


}
```

if it was a local server, I would have update my PHP.ini with more memory and do the job.

However, I have a LIVE server and it has to be done in the live server and I have no control or power over PHP.ini.

What to do? How can I do it easily that I will not get a memory issue?

Please help if anyone?

Comment: Can we see some code?

Comment: would that help, the code works....its the issue of getting each row parsing the url and updating that row.

Comment: If the code works you wouldn't be here asking questions. **Please post the relevant code**.

Comment: hahaha :) you are correct my friend, give me a sec I will update

Comment: @Strawberry please have a look now

Comment: @Strawberry Can this be done with SQL only?? or you need something like PLSQL??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
UPDATE [table_name] SET product_id = CONVERT(SUBSTR(url, LOCATE('products/', url)+9, LOCATE('/compare',url)-LOCATE('products/', url)+9),UNSIGNED INTEGER)
```

But this will only works if every `url` field has suffix as `/compare`

Comment: You can even do a relationship with `products` table to check weather id is correct or not using that converted integer value before assigning it directly to product_id column.

Answer (score 0):

if you use MariaDB you can use **REGEXP_REPLACE** to do the changes like

```
UPDATE your_table
 SET url = REGEXP_REPLACE(url,'[0-9]+',Product_id)
WHERE Product_id > 0;
```

**sample**

```
MariaDB [your_schema]> SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('http://example.com/products/12/compare','[0-9]+','99');
+--------------------------------------------------------------------+
| REGEXP_REPLACE('http://example.com/products/12/compare','[0-9]+','99') |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------+
| http://example.com/products/99/compare                                 |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [your_schema]>
```

Comment: Can this be done with SQL? I dont think so? you need PLSQL or something similar

Comment: It's the contrary of that solution than you want to do right ? You want to find the ID that is in your URL and update your product_id with it ?

Answer (score 0):

I have a pretty odd idea but it can work.
Look at that query :

```sql
SELECT 
'http://example.com/products/12/compare' as url,
'http://example.com/products/' as check1,
'http://example.com/termsets/' as check2,
'http://example.com/products/12/compare' REGEXP 'http://example.com/products/' as regexp_check1,    -- check 1
SUBSTRING('http://example.com/products/12/compare', LOCATE('http://example.com/products/','http://example.com/products/12/compare')+LENGTH('http://example.com/products/'),1 ) as test1,
SUBSTRING('http://example.com/products/12/compare', LOCATE('http://example.com/products/','http://example.com/products/12/compare')+LENGTH('http://example.com/products/'),1 ) REGEXP "^[0-9]+$" as test1_only_num,
SUBSTRING('http://example.com/products/12/compare', LOCATE('http://example.com/products/','http://example.com/products/12/compare')+LENGTH('http://example.com/products/'),2 ) as test11,
SUBSTRING('http://example.com/products/12/compare', LOCATE('http://example.com/products/','http://example.com/products/12/compare')+LENGTH('http://example.com/products/'),1 ) REGEXP "^[0-9]+$" as test11_only_num,
SUBSTRING('http://example.com/products/12/compare', LOCATE('http://example.com/products/','http://example.com/products/12/compare')+LENGTH('http://example.com/products/'),3 ) as test111,
SUBSTRING('http://example.com/products/12/compare', LOCATE('http://example.com/products/','http://example.com/products/12/compare')+LENGTH('http://example.com/products/'),1 ) REGEXP "^[0-9]+$" as test111_only_num;
```

Result :

```
+----------------------------------------+------------------------------+------------------------------+---------------+-------+----------------+--------+-----------------+---------+------------------+
| url                                    | check1                       | check2                       | regexp_check1 | test1 | test1_only_num | test11 | test11_only_num | test111 | test111_only_num |
+----------------------------------------+------------------------------+------------------------------+---------------+-------+----------------+--------+-----------------+---------+------------------+
| http://example.com/products/12/compare | http://example.com/products/ | http://example.com/termsets/ | 1             | 1     | 1              | 12     | 1               | 12/     | 0                |
+----------------------------------------+------------------------------+------------------------------+---------------+-------+----------------+--------+-----------------+---------+------------------+
```

`Url, check1 and check2` are just to display the variables I'm using. It's a main ID, the query is not usable that way of course.

## Logic with `check1`

1. You check with a REGEX if `check1` is present in your `URL`. If yes, `regexp_check1` is 1, else it's 0.

   2. ONLY if `regexp_check1` is 1, then you `SUBSTRING` your URL to take the part that is located AFTER the `check1` sentence. You take the first character AFTER (`test1`), then the two characters AFTER (`test11`), the three characters AFTER (`test111`) etc.. until the max length your ID_PRODUCT can be (6 or 7 for example).
2. You REGEX the SUBSTR you isolated to check if they are numeric only (`test1`  is numeric, `test11` is numeric only, `test111` is not numeric only.
3. Then you know that the content of `test11` is your ID

Then you do the same thing with `check2` if `regexp_check1` was 0, and with an eventual `check3` (which would contain http://www.comadso.dk/products/ for example), and for every beginning you can have.

Maybe my idea is a shitty one, but hey if it's seem dumb but works, it's not dumb !